# Show an aggregated list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my model I have data similar to:

```
$scope.list = [{id:0,tags:['tag1','tag2']},{id:2,tags:['tag2']}};
```

I want to show a list of tags (contains unique values of 'tag1' and 'tag2') with checkboxes. Hopefully something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in list.tags">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.tag" />
        {{tag}}
    </label>
</div>
```

I know how to filter the main list based on whats checked if I hard code the list, but not how to generate the list of unique tags automatically.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are looking to perform three operations:

- Get the array of tags from each item in `$scope.list`
- Flatten these into a single array
- Get the unique values from this array

You can do this with pure JavaScript, but to make things easier, I would recommend using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), a library that gives you access to many functions for manipulating and inspecting arrays, objects, and so forth.

Let's start with this code:

```
$scope.list = [
  {id: 0, tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']},
  {id: 1, tags: ['tag2']},
  {id: 2, tags: ['tag1', 'tag3', 'tag4']},
  {id: 3, tags: ['tag3', 'tag4']}
];
```

Now, let's perform the first operation: get the array from the `tags` property for each object in `$scope.list`. Underscore provides the [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) method, which is just what we need.

> **pluck** `_.pluck(list, propertyName)`
>
> A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case for map: extracting a list of property values.

Using pluck, we can get the following:

```
var tags = _.pluck($scope.list, 'tags');
// gives us [['tag1', 'tag2'], ['tag2'], ['tag1', 'tag3', 'tag4'], ['tag3', 'tag4']]
```

Now, we want to flatten that array.

> **flatten** `_.flatten(array, [shallow])`
>
> Flattens a nested array (the nesting can be to any depth). If you pass shallow, the array will only be flattened a single level.

```
tags = _.flatten(tags);
// gives us ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag2', 'tag1', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag3', 'tag4']
```

Finally, you only want one instance of each tag.

> **uniq** `_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iterator])` Alias: `unique`
>
> Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iterator function.

```
tags = _.unique(tags)
// gives us ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']
```

We can combine these together with Underscore's useful [`chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) method to chain these together. Let's create a function on the scope that returns the unique tags:

```
$scope.uniqueTags = function() {
  return _.chain($scope.list)
    .pluck('tags')
    .flatten()
    .unique()
    .value();
};
```

Since this is a function, it will always return the unique tags, no matter if we add or remove items in `$scope.list` after the fact.

Now you can use `ng-repeat` on `uniqueTags` to show each tag:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in uniqueTags()">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.tag" />
    {{tag}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Here is a working jsFiddle that demonstrates this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/cqTKG/

Comment: Perfect! And a great explanation as well!

Comment: Thanks! Happy to have helped. ^_^

Comment: What is performance like for using such an aggregation function? How often will Angular call the function?

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom filter to get a unique set/array of tags, suitable for use with ng-repeat:

```
.filter('uniqueTags', function() {
    return function(list) {
        var tags = {};
        angular.forEach(list, function(obj, key) {
            angular.forEach(obj.tags, function(value) {
                tags[value] = 1;
            })
        });
        var uniqueTags = []
        for (var key in tags) {
            uniqueTags.push(key);
        }
        return uniqueTags;
    }
});
```

I first put the tags into an object, which automatically gives us uniqueness.  Then I convert it to an array.

Use as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in list | uniqueTags">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/4Bu8Z/).

---

The following may not do what I think you probably want/expect it to do:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.tag">
```

This does not create $scope properties `filter.tag1` and `filter.tag2` on the controller scope (i.e., the scope where ng-repeat is used).  Each iteration of ng-repeat creates its own child scope, so the ng-model above will create scope property `filter.tag` on each ng-repeat child scope, as shown in my fiddle.