# ngTagsInput get and parse data from database

Tags: angularjs, json, input, to-json

When I use ngTagsInput before send to database I do:

```
angular.toJson($scope.tags);
```

When I make get I receive something like this in my scope {{}}:

```
[{"text":"abc"},{"text":"cba"},{"text":"tag"}]
```

What can I do to show my tags like this:

```
abc, cba, tag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in tags"><span ng-if="!$first">, </span><span>{{value.text}}</span></span>
```

Or with Underscore in code:

```
var str = _.pluck(list, 'text').join(', ')
```

Other options here: [Show an aggregated list in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163027/show-an-aggregated-list-in-angularjs)